# Access to "CreatingControls.InstallerControl.InitializeComponent ()" is not possible because of the security level

Tags: c#

Hallo
I am a beginning programmer and facing already different types of problems.
Could anybody perhaps be so kind to assist/deal with this one for example.

Access to "CreatingControls.InstallerControl.InitializeComponent ()" is not possible because of the security level (Original in German: "Der Zugriff auf "CreatingControls.InstallerControl.InitializeComponent()" ist aufgrund der Sicherheitsebene nicht möglich. ...")

My current and base classes are all public. But I can't inialize the components? any idea is duly appreciated.

debru

Comment: "failed to access blah.deblah....() because of the security level".

Comment: Google Translate result: "Access to "CreatingControls.InstallerControl.InitializeComponent ()" is not possible because the security level"

Comment: 1) Please use English!

2) Please specify your programming language.

3) Please specify the software program (compiler) which generates such output.

Comment: I am sorry but i posted the error as it is reported by the debugger in german version as it is. the language is c#.

Comment: please include the whole call stack and your code that is executing when this exception occurs.  

You can get these by wrapping your code in a "try {} catch (Exception ex) {}" block.  The ex variable in the exception handler will have the call stack.

Answer (score 1):

InitializeComponent is automatically generated by VisualStudio when you create a new Form.
It is declared as private and thus cannot be accessed from outside the class.
You should make sure that you are not trying to call it from anywhere else, it is basically intended to give the Form Designer a single place to initialize the components of a form.

Comment: thank you very much Kevin Wienhold for the answer. But what about when I am creating the controls as user created code  instead of getting them generated by the Form Designer?
Shouldn't i still be able to initialize those components?

Comment: Of course you are able to initialize controls that you add in code, but if you want to call the method that handles the initialization from the outside it can't be private, so you can't place your custom initialization code in InitializeComponent.
You could simply create a public method that creates your controls and sets them up, just like InitializeComponent does for controls added by the graphic designer.
You may also want to consider why you have to initialize controls from the outside, since this is something that usually remains within the control or form.

Comment: many thanks again, Kevin Wienhold. I am back again to where i was yesterday. I am sorry but I don't really get it. I just added classes to my Project and then I have to (I want to) add Construt (initialise) these classes, which are derived from a base class. This particular member is declared as PROTECTED in the base class and as public in the sub-classes. But when I call the method: InitializeComponent() from within the subclasses, it fails to accept, where I get the message I posted yesterday. I will appreciate again if you could a bit more hint for me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't edit the code-behind.  If you want to change the way a control looks/works/init go to the designer and use that.  This will change the correct things.